# Fast detection on circles on a Bitmapdata in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, math, bitmapdata

in AS3 I'm looking for a way to detect the circles on a BitmapData image as fast as possible. Any idea or advice?

The BitmapData is actually a photo taken with the iPhone camera, so what I need is an algorithm to detect circular shapes (Hough transform implementation?)

Answer (score 0):

I got your points now. Thanks.

I found [this](https://github.com/bsdnoobz/opencv-code/blob/master/shape-detect.cpp) OpenCV library and a tutorial about how it works [here](http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/detecting-simple-shapes-in-an-image/)
Maybe will be necessary to port OpenCV to AS3 (maybe we already have something similar)
You can also create a [Native Extension](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html)

Comment: Maybe my question was unclear: I need to extract circular shapes from a photo

Comment: Thanks, I'll check OpenCV

Comment: I get errors when including OpenCv framework in a Native Extension for IOS. Any idea? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022038/error-when-including-opencv-framework-in-a-native-extension-for-ios