# Error when including OpenCv framework in a Native Extension for IOS

Tags: ios, apache-flex, opencv, ane

I'm creating an ANE for IOS that implements the OpenCV framework, but when I compile the app on Flash Builder I get this error:

```
Error occurred while packaging the application:

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "__ZNKSt3__120__vector_base_commonILb1EE20__throw_length_errorEv", referenced from:
      __ZNSt3__16vectorIN2cv3VecIiLi128EEENS_9allocatorIS3_EEE8__appendEm in opencv2(matrix.o)
      __ZNSt3__16vectorIN2cv3VecIiLi64EEENS_9allocatorIS3_EEE8__appendEm in opencv2(matrix.o)
      __ZNSt3__16vectorIN2cv3VecIiLi32EEENS_9allocatorIS3_EEE8__appendEm in opencv2(matrix.o)
      __ZNSt3__16vectorIN2cv3VecIiLi16EEENS_9allocatorIS3_EEE8__appendEm in opencv2(matrix.o)
      __ZNSt3__16vectorIN2cv3VecIiLi12EEENS_9allocatorIS3_EEE8__appendEm in opencv2(matrix.o)
      __ZNSt3__16vectorIN2cv3VecIiLi9EEENS_9allocatorIS3_EEE8__appendEm in opencv2(matrix.o)
      __ZNSt3__16vectorIN2cv3VecIiLi8EEENS_9allocatorIS3_EEE8__appendEm in opencv2(matrix.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
Compilation failed while executing : ld64
```

The error occurred after I added this line

```
<option>-framework opencv2</option>
```

to the linkerOption on the platformOptions.xml

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
I've added this line

```
<option>-lc++</option>
```

to the platformOptions.xml.

Now OpenCV works great in my actionscript native extension.